# Precise definition of a telescoping series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Is there a precise definition of a telescoping series?

I'm not an analyst, but I need to teach the analysis portion of a course this coming semester. The coursebook we are using does not define what a telescoping series is, but just gives some examples.

In the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series), they say that a  telescoping series is a series of the form $$\left( \sum_{k=0}^n a_{k+1} - a_k \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$$ where $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ some sequence. This seems to align with most examples of series that are called "telescoping", but I vaguely remember seeing series in my undergraduate analysis days that involved more complicated cancellations and were referred to as telescoping.

Is there a more general definition of a telescoping series than this one?

Comment: I would not worry about precisely defining what a telescoping series is, but rather use "telescoping" as a description of a type of approach that helps in determining the sum. For example, you can use the limit comparison test, the integral test, telescoping method, etc. in working with series. Naturally, it's helpful to say "telescoping series", so do this, but this is not something you need to get your students all worked up about. In fact, I doubt any students (maybe one or two at most . . .) will even be concerned with what exactly a "telescoping series" is if you don't worry them over it.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro. There's always a few curious students who want to ask about very precise and technical definitions, so it would be nice to know. And I'm curious as well. :)

Comment: I've definitely had experience with this -- both sides, as a student and as a teacher. As a teacher you mainly want to avoid getting too side-tracked on things like this in class, and instead try to get the two or three interested students to see you afterwards (e.g. office hours).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yep that's right---I just want to have something useful to say during office hours on the topic.

Comment: Regarding "involved more complicated cancellations", these can arise when you're using partial fraction expansions to expand a rational function summand. You can probably find some examples with this search -- [series + sum + "partial fractions" + telescoping](https://www.google.com/search?q=series+sum+%22partial+fractions%22+telescoping&filter=0). Speaking of partial fraction expansions, sometimes they can be used to find patterns in higher derivatives of a rational function, something I learned surprisingly late -- see my comments [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/26487/745).